# What are the applications of $\lambda$-rings to class field theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, lambda-rings

In the book *Lambda Rings* by Yau, he mentions several areas where $\lambda$-rings can be applied, but he doesn't go into much details. He even includes class field theory in the list, mentioning "finite étale $\Bbb Q$-algebras, cyclotomic fields and (un)ramified primes". What are these applications of $\lambda$-rings to class field theory?

Comment: This is all explained wonderfully in papers by Borger and Borger-de Smit...

Comment: @user5831 thanks for the pointer!